# not getting the expected output of intent

Tags: android

so basically i am using intent in this.so when i clicked on the splash page the main_activity page  should open.but after running the  code splash page opens ..but when i click on the textview blank page opens.even in the logcat sections there are no errors.

this is my SplashActivity.class code

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

this is my main_activity.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/plain_text_input"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="142dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="142dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="439dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_username"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="USERNAME"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtusername"
        android:layout_width="351dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="51dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="381dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="78dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="78dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="325dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_password"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="PASSWORD"
        android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="353dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="43dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="260dp" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="348dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="170dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/DeepPink"
        app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="373dp"
            android:layout_height="73dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="157dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:freezesText="true"
                android:text="LOGIN "
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="25dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="149dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="149dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="98dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="SIGN IN"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="101dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="101dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="39dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="FORGOT PASSWORD!"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="106dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="108dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="495dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ticket" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="598dp"
        android:text="CheckBox"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        tools:text="ADMIN" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my splash.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<RelativeLayout tools:context=".SplashActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView android:layout_height="173dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" app:srcCompat="@drawable/ticket"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:maxHeight="42dp" android:maxWidth="42dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="399dp" android:layout_marginEnd="98dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"/>

    <TextView android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_width="349dp" android:layout_marginBottom="231dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:id="@+id/textView" android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="30dp" android:textColor="@color/WhiteSmoke" android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:text="Movie Ticket Booking" android:fontFamily="sans-serif"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my Mainactivity.java code

```
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

}
```

Comment: Share with us the onCreate method of your MainActivity.

Comment: import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

}

Comment: Is that all you got in your MainActivity? I need the onCreate method

Comment: import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code in MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    setContentView (R.layout.main_activity);
    }
}
```